# Breaking out of while loop using an exception

Tags: python, events, exception

ok so say I have a Tkinter window and a while loop going on. The Tkinter window is being run in a separate thread, and the while loop is in main. Ex:

```
  def quit_me():
      raise ValueError("Exception to quit while loop")
      exit()
  root = Tk()
  start_new_thread(root.mainloop,())
  root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", quit_me)
  def main():
      while (true):
          try:
              pass #do stuff here
          except ValueError:
              break
```

Is this possible? I have tried it in my application but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there a better way to do this? Any ideas?

Comment: What's not working?  Are you sure the ValueError is being raised?  and did you mean `while True` instead of `while true`?

Comment: I just typed that little snippet up. Sorry about the case. Whats not working was that the exception was not being caught by the try, except. But as Greg Hewgill confirmed what I suspected, exceptions aren't thrown across threads.

Comment: Try a `sys.exit()` in the place of your `raise`

Answer (score 2):

Exceptions are not thrown across threads. Unless your `#do stuff here` is actually calling the `quit_me()` function eventually, your main thread will never see the thrown exception.

You can probably do this with a global:

```
QuitNow = False

def quit_me():
    QuitNow = True

def main():
    while not QuitNow:
        #do stuff here
```

Comment: So there is no other way besides a global?

Comment: Sure there are other ways, but a global is probably the simplest. For example, you could set up a (thread-safe!) queue of events that are processed by the main thread, and when you want to exit you can put an event on that queue that tells the main thread to exit.